# How to specify a newer version of Elasticsearch in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

How to specify a newer version of Elasticsearch in spring-boot for the following library. This needs to be a gradle dependency

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch', version: '2.3.4.RELEASE'

    say 7.9.1 instead of 7.6.2
```

Will it work against a newer version?

Comment: Are you using gradle or maven maybe?

Comment: do you need a newer version of the library? You should be able to use this version with a 7.9.1 cluster

Comment: @michalk This needs to be a gradle dependency

Comment: @P.J.Meisch 2.3.4.RELEASE seems to be supporting 7.6.2, want to know how to use 7.9.1 and point to the latest ES

Comment: AFAIK, you will have to wait untill spring include latest version of elasticsearch but if your really need it, would have use high level rest client and disable auto elasticsearch configuration to use it.

Comment: @code_mechanic can you be more specific on the fix which needs to be done in the gradle file. Will spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch automatically use a higher version of the high level rest client and hence be able to point to the recent ES version

Comment: spring-data-elasticsearch, which is an abstraction of elasticsearch using spring-data project, which provides auto configuration and let you define properties so that you don't have to configure it yourself, it uses pre defined version of elasticsearch which you cannot change.......... If you want to use latest elasticsearch version, you need let go off spring-data-elasticsearch completely from your project

Comment: high level rest client is another library provided by elasticsearch which aligns with their versions, but that would require you to configure it yourself, adding a dependency like normal dependency then creating `RestClient` beans yourself in code and then you can use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to update your application to a newer version if you do not use some native Elasticsearch library stuff in your application which is not available in 7.6.2.

Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0.4 (pulled in by Spring Boot 2.3.4) is built with the Elasticsearch client libraries in version 7.6.2, but these client libraries can communicate with an Elasticsearch cluster in version 7.9.1, there were no changes in the client communication protocol as far as I know.

You will get a warning in the log:

> WARN  [main] o.s.d.elasticsearch.support.VersionInfo  : Version mismatch in between Elasticsearch Client and Cluster: 7.6.2 - 7.9.1

but you can ignore that.